# Quoted fields escaped in smarter_csv

Tags: ruby, csv, smartercsv

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to process with smarter_csv in Ruby. Every field has double quuotes and there are some fields that have double quotes nested within them that are not escaped. I'm using `:force_simple_split => true` [as suggested in the documentation](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv#notes-on-improper-quotation-and-unwanted-characters-in-headers) to fix this situation. However, when I try to process the file every field has escaped quotes within it. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm opening a csv file that was generated from a Windows server that looks something like this...

`header1,header2,header3
"field1, There are "nested quotes" here.","field2", "field3"`

I open the file with smarter_csv like so...

`c = SmarterCSV.process('myfile.csv', force_simple_split: true, file_encoding: "iso-8859-1", row_sep: "\r")`

Then I get output like this...

`{:header1=>"\"field1, There are \"nested quotes\"",
  :header2=>"\"field2\"",
  :header3=>"\"field3\""
}`

Comment: [please file an issue](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> SmarterCSV::VERSION
 => "1.0.19"
> options = {:force_simple_split => true}
> ap SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/quoted.csv', options)
[
   {
        :header1 => "\"field1",
        :header2 => "There are \"nested quotes\" here.\"",
        :header3 => "\"field2\""
    }
]
```

`force_simple_split` does just that .. it does not allow for embedded :col_sep characters in your data.

Please note that your example CSV data contains an embedded comma, and that the simple split of the line with the data results in four fields, not three.

Because you don't provide a fourth header, the fourth field is ignored.

Please open an issue for correct handling of quoted data as in your example

Comment: But it is splitting at the wrong place. Ideally the value for header1 should be "field1, There are \"nested quotes\" here."